# Ошибка "native typeface cannot be made" при использовании шрифта

Tags: android, ttf, otf

Скачал шрифт ttf и поместил в папку assets/fonts.. полный адрес папки: app\src\main\assets\fonts

Вытаскиваю в активити:

```
Typeface myfonts = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/a_AntiqueTitulGr.ttf"); 
mSelectedItemView.setTypeface(myfonts);
```

Компилируется нормально, но приложение выдает ошибку. Посмотрел какая: "native typeface cannot be made".

Нашел решение,что возможно идет утечка памяти. Как решение создал класс:

```
    public class Utils {

private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface getTypeFace(Context context, String assetPath) {
            synchronized (cache) {
                if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
                    try {
                        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), assetPath);
                        cache.put(assetPath, typeFace);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("TypeFaces", "Typeface not loaded.");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
                return cache.get(assetPath);
            }
        }
}
```

И вытаскивал теперь вот так:

```
 Typeface myfonts = Utils.getTypeFace(this, "fonts/a_BentTitulDcFr.ttf");
    mSelectedItemView.setTypeface(myfonts);
```

Ошибка исчезла. Приложение запустилось. Но шрифт не меняется. Как решить эту проблему? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Еще пишут, что иногда помогает такое решение. В gradle пропишите

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }
```

Comment: Нет, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась банальная. Нельзя использовать верхний регистр и всякие дефисы в названии шрифта

```
fonts/a_AntiqueTitulGr.ttf - не верно

fonts/antiquetitulgr.ttf - верно
```

Не забудьте переименовать его и в папке `fonts`.